# Trouble mapping over iterable props object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble reconciling an error I keep encountering while working through the examples in React's own documentation.

It seems as though whenever I'm passing a props object into a function component, and then mapping over an iterable object stored in the props (in this case an array stored in `numbers`), that object is somehow no longer available going into the map operation and returns undefined.

Here's my code; [one of many snippets provided in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys) which I've observed failing this case:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li>{props.value}</li>
  );
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;

  console.log(numbers, typeof numbers);

  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>Feel-Better Chicken and Rice Soup
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export default NumberList;
```

I've included a console.log on line 13 for debugging purposes, and here's an [image](https://res.cloudinary.com/da6db8qdd/image/upload/v1551199618/2019-02-26_11-46-03.png) of the error output (showing where the code execution is breaking):

I'm reviewing the docs for practice using the latest version of Create-React-App. My dependencies in package.json are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
  "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
}
```

One thing that seems strange to me is that the third error line in the console output references `renderWithHooks`. I haven't started learning hooks yet as I've been working to firm up my understanding of React's basic concepts before moving forward to hooks. I don't want to sound like an idiot, but as many of the similar example snippets provided in React docs aren't working (they work only in the CodePen examples) is it possible the latest version of React (16.8) is not compliant with the syntax I'm following in the docs?

Otherwise, I'm at a loss as to why these examples aren't working.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is that all of your code? because when I put that in codesandbox it works with no errors. https://codesandbox.io/s/0p371wpvwp

Comment: Why is it called three times on your side? I have the output once locally and on codepen (you can specify versions of libs by clicking on the cog at the top-left corner of JS code).

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, no, this wasn't all my code. The error was due to making another call to `ReactDOM.render()` in Create-React-App's index.js file.

Now that I've imported both the `NumberList` component and the `numbers` array into index.js, calling the `ReactDOM.render()` there updates the UI with the expected output.